# Two definition of simply connected region in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have some question on the definition of simply connected region in complex analysis.

In the textbook of complex analysis I have, the author defined the definition of simply connected region as follows;

A region $\Omega$ such that for any rectangle whose circumference is in $\Omega$, if the all interior points of the rectangle are also in $\Omega$, then we call $\Omega$ simply connected region.

But it seems that he tacitly use the fact when $\Omega$ is simply connected and $\Gamma$ is closed curve in $\Omega$,(here, closed curve means which starting point=end point) then all interior points of $\Gamma$ is contained in $\Omega$. (here interior points are the all points enclosed by $\Gamma$)

If we define the definition of simply connected region as the above, (For any closed curve $\Gamma \subset \Omega$, if all interior points of $\Gamma$ is contained in $\Omega$, then $\Omega$ is simply connected region.

I think these two definitions are equivalent. (One direction is obvious!) 
But I don't know how to show the converse direction.(That is to show from rectangle to closed curve.)

I also know the accurate definition of simply connected region using Riemann sphere or the ones used in topology defined by contraction to one point. But I want to know using not such concept and would content myself with the above definition using closed curve at least in complex analysis. (Because I want to teach this definition to someone with easier and intuitive one! The definition using closed curve is the very one I desire.)

Any comment will be highly appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining the interior of an arbitrary closed curve?

Comment: Your first definition is not equivalent. Now if instead of rectangle you say polygon or piece-wise linear simple closed curve. Then it is equivalent but rectangle is not enough. Just consider a region shaped like a + with a slight smaller + taken out of the interior. There is clear a large + shaped hole. But if you make it correctly no rectangle can go around it and stay inside the larger +. So for this region the interior of any rectangle will still be in the space even though the interior of an arbitrary polygon will not.

Comment: Azarel, you are right. It invokes the Jordan Curve theorem and notion of bounded component. No way to say it so simple, even though second definition. Owen, I am very thankful for striking example. I never thought it. By the way, what does it mean the piece-wise linear simple closed curve? Is it not sufficient for only simple closed curve?